# Why are my custom framework classes not automatically available?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

So, I created a custom static library (framework). Then, in another project, I went to my targets 'Build Phases' tab and added my custom framework under 'Link Binary With Libraries'. It worked fine and my framework shows up just like any other (.framework, yellow toolbox, etc). However, when I attempt to use some of the classes and methods in that framework, they do not automatically show up as suggestions when I begin typing. If I type them in completely, then run the project everything works fine. Its just that they don't come up as automatic suggestions.

I've done something similar to this before and I didn't have this problem. I'm not sure what I'm missing...

Comment: Classes have to be required somewhere before showing up on the suggestions. Did import the .h file somewhere before trying to find it as a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you imported the correct header files for the framework?

Xcode (at least since version 4, as far as I can remember) won't provide suggestions for classes unless you import their header files, even if they're included as part of your project.